# How can I properly set up jRAPL in my Maven project in IntelliJ if I cannot access activate() and deactivate() methods?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jmh

I use jRAPL, java microbench harness, maven projeckt. I imported jRAPL to my project. Do not accsess to activate() and deactivate() methods. IntelliJ is not letting me to access it. I try to measure the energy consumption of addBenchmark(). IntelliJ does not access to activate() and deactivate() methods. need help ?

```
package BenchMark_JMH;
import jRAPL.*;
import com.ProductManagerArrayList;


import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import pro.Product;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(1)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public class ProductManagerArrayListBenchmark {

    private ProductManagerArrayList productManager;
    SyncEnergyMonitor  monitor;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        productManager = new ProductManagerArrayList();
        monitor = new SyncEnergyMonitor();
        monitor.activate();


    }

    @Benchmark
    public void addBenchmark() {
        monitor.activate();
        EnergyStats before = monitor.getSample();
        Product product = new Product(4, "Product 4", 40000);
        productManager.add(product);

        EnergyStats after = monitor.getSample();
        EnergyDiff diff = EnergyDiff.between(before,after);
        monitor.deactivate();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Product getBenchmark() {
        return productManager.get(2);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void updateBenchmark() {
        Product product = new Product(2, "Updated Product", 50000);
        productManager.update(product);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void deleteBenchmark() {
        productManager.delete(3);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Product> getAllBenchmark() {
        return productManager.getAll();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int sizeBenchmark() {
        return productManager.size();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int getIDBenchmark() {
        Product product = new Product(1, "Product 1", 10000);
        return productManager.getID(product);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void setBenchmark() {
        Product product = new Product(1, "Updated Product", 20000);
        productManager.set(1, product);
    }
}
```

I searched online and used all methods but failed. I expect someone to help me to set up correctly  etc.

Comment: this message comes up; Cannot resolve method 'activate' in 'SyncEnergyMonitor'